# Display records from database one at a time on a single webpage

Tags: php, mysql

I current have the following records of questions in my database.

```
|QuestionID|QuestionText|
|1|What is the HTTP port number?|
|2|What is the Telnet port number?|
|3|What is the FTP port number?|
```

1. I would like to display each question one at a time on a single webpage using PHP scripting.
2. The user can view the next question by clicking on the 'next' button.
3. I would also like to include 'previous' button to allow the user to go back to the previous page.
4. In addition to this, how can I determine the amount of time the user spent on each of the question (QuestionID)?

Even if I tried using the following loop method of clicking next to view the next question but I am also having problems viewing the next question,what is wrong ?

```
if(isset($_POST['next']))    
{   
    $a=$_POST['a'];    
}

if(!isset($a))    
{  
    $a=0;       
}
echo $a;

$questionquery="SELECT * FROM QuestionBank Limit 1 OFFSET $a ";

$questionresult=mysql_query($questionquery) or die ('Query failed:'. mysql_error());

echo "<form method='post' action=''>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($questionresult))
{
    echo $row['QuestionText'];   
}

$a = $a+1;

echo "<input type='hidden' value='$a' name 'a'>";  
echo "<input type='submit' name='next' value='next'>";
```

Comment: The question is a little broad, but if you wanna use a single page to display 1 question at a time, Ajax would be your best bet, using JQuery for example. and you would need to rewrite your php so it serves 1 question at a time based on parameters you define. Finally about the time the user spends on the question, the best option would be to record the time when you served a question (server side) and again after they press "next" and by simple difference you get the time.

Answer (score 2):

From question 1 to 3, it's just pagination.
You can use : http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/29.html. Just edit some parts and you're good to do.

For question 4, you can just use `time()` at the start of the webpage. And when the user go to the next page, you can set `time()` again and get the time difference.

Hope this help out a little(: